# How I can fix this problem ? No module name ‘bson.code’

Tags: python

I want to use pymongodb so I did this two commands.

```
pip install pymongo
pip install bson
```

And I tried running with this code. (No other code just only this)

```
import pymongo
```

But I got this problem.

```
ModuleNotFoundError No module named ‘bson.code’
```

Please help me !

Comment: Are you sure you've installed those modules in the same Python installation as you're running your code in? Are you sure you're not shadowing the bson module with your own `bson.py` or something of the sort?

Comment: I just installed it with ‘pip install bson’
But If it occur error with ‘pypi bson installing’, then how to install bson right way?

Answer (score 4):

From the pymongo `README.rst`:

```
Do not install the "bson" package from pypi. PyMongo comes with its own bson package; doing "easy_install bson" installs a third-party package that is incompatible with PyMongo.
```

I suspect this is your problem ...

Edit: Here is the link to the docs: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html?highlight=bson#installing-upgrading

Comment: But If i don’t run this command ‘pip install bson’, it gives me this problem ‘No module named ‘bson’’

Comment: What is "it" in this case? Not `import pymongo` I suspect?

Comment: Also, I suggest you zap your virtual env and recreate it to be on the safe side now, since you basically had 2 versions of bson installed previously.

Comment: `import pymongo` right. If i don’t install bson module, i can get that problem `No modulle named ‘bson’`.

Comment: Now I uninstalled all module and just installed pymongo. And then there is other way to install bson??

Comment: You don't need to. It's included with pymongo.

Comment: But if i just install pymongo, error named ‘No module named ‘bson’’ occur

Comment: And i am coding now in pythonista.

Comment: Not according to the pymongo docs, which makes me think your env is screwed.  Suggest you just remove the current env and recreate it with only pymongo.

Comment: While i reinstall pymongo, i got this problem.

Comment: `TypeError("int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'OmniClass'",)
Failed to run setup.py
Fall back to directory guessing`

Comment: I run it in stash

Comment: No idea what stash is either, sorry.